# Mac listener on port 80

Tags: macos, http, web, cloud

I want to test a cloud service which calls a URL but I dont know the format of the payload. I dont particularly want to code something up I just want to verify that the caller calls the URL and I can see the shape of message it passes. I think it will be an HTTP post to a URL of my choice - in this case a DYNDNS URL.

Can anybody suggest an appropriate bit of software to listen on port 80 of my mac and dump everything that comes through that port so I can see the URL / data passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netcat can listen on a port and show you what arrives quite easily. It is installed on a Mac OSX as plain `nc`. See documentation [here](http://netcat.sourceforge.net) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nc.1.html).

Try this in a Terminal window:

```
man nc
```

And:

```
nc -l 80
```

You may need `sudo` on the front of that because 80 is a privileged port.